# Considering AWS KMS, what would be a proper solution when the encrypted data is used pretty often?

Tags: php, amazon-kms

I am studying AWS KMS applied to PHP application.
What happens with performance when the encrypted/decrypted data is heavily used?

On solution would be calling AWS KMS pretty often, let's say once per script run. But I am worried about the performance of my php application because of the roundtrips to aws.

An alternative, which I don't like that much is to call AWS KMS once per session: I just decrypt what I need and then keep it as session variable.

What would be the proper design pattern when the data that needs to be kept is used pretty often?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could've used [AWS Encryption SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html?shortFooter=true) to implement [data key caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/data-key-caching.html) which would solve the problem of calling KMS endpoint each time you want to decrypt. But, the Encryption SDK is not available for PHP. I'm not aware of any other solutions :(

Comment: Hi @sudo, any idea what kind of performance (encryption operations per second) you get with data key caching?